# Can't display in GridView data from Parse.com object that contains a Pointer field - Android

Tags: java, android, gridview, parse-platform, android-asynctask

I want to fill a gridview using data from an object named `Shop_photos`that has the below structure and rows in it:
[image]

---

The problem in the below code is that even though I am filling the searchlist with the result (I checked that because the message "I AM HERE" which is inside the `for` is being printed as it should), the flag become `false` for some reason and and I get the toast about no valid shop photos and I go back to the previous page, as I say in the `else` part in `onPostExecute`.

This is the Logcat:

```
04-27 17:29:42.400  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all time:161438256
04-27 17:29:44.142  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all time:161439997
04-27 17:29:44.472  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all D/width of screen﹕ 480
04-27 17:29:44.492  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-27 17:29:44.762  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all D/SHOP ID1﹕ QfqCIzTSRg
04-27 17:29:45.013  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all D/I AM HERE﹕ [ 04-27 17:29:45.043 30431:30431 I/Choreographer ]
    Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-27 17:29:47.065  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all D/SHOP SUGGESTION﹕ Costa Coffee Nicosia
04-27 17:29:47.065  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/MemoryCache﹕ MemoryCache will use up to 32.0MB
04-27 17:29:47.075  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 442 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-27 17:29:47.355  30431-30817/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/MemoryCache﹕ cache size=76800 length=1
04-27 17:29:47.405  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-27 17:29:47.695  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41ffbda8 time:161443549
04-27 17:29:47.695  30431-30431/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41f2a440 time:161443549
```

---

This is the fragment in which I do the query to fill the `result` object:

```
public class ViewShopsPhotosFragment extends Fragment {

    protected ProgressDialog proDialog;

    private long mLastClickTime = 0;

    String shopname = null;
    String shopid = null;

    GridView gridview;
    List<ParseObject> ob;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    List<PhotosList> photosarraylist = null;

    boolean flag_photos = false;

    View convertView = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        proDialog = CustomProgressDialog.ctor(this.getActivity());

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewshopsphoto, container, false);

                Parse.initialize(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "hoMaKMBjhkjh", "wWV193mEtPqbhjgh");

                // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
                new RemoteDataTask().execute();

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            proDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            photosarraylist = new ArrayList<PhotosList>();

            final ParseQuery<ParseObject> shop = ParseQuery.getQuery("Shop");
            shop.whereEqualTo("name", shopname); //shop name

            shop.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(final List<ParseObject> shopList, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        shopid = shopList.get(0).getObjectId();

                        Log.d("SHOP ID1", shopid);

                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query_photos = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Shop_photos");
                        query_photos.whereEqualTo("name", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Shop", shopid)); //shop name

                        //pio prosfati prwta
                        query_photos.orderByDescending("updatedAt");

                        try {
                            ob = query_photos.find();

                            for (ParseObject photo : ob) {
                                Log.d("I AM HERE", "");

                                flag_photos = true;

                                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) photo.get("photo");
                                PhotosList photolist = new PhotosList();

                                photolist.setPhoto(image.getUrl());
                                photolist.setShopname(shopname);

                                photosarraylist.add(photolist);
                            }
                        } catch (ParseException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("shop", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            if (flag_photos) {
                // Locate the gridview in gridview_main.xml
                gridview = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photos_grid);

                // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
                adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), photosarraylist);

                // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
                gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "We couldn't find any photos for this shop!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), BaseActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("flag_showshop", "Y");
                intent.putExtra("shopname", shopname);

                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);

                proDialog.hide();

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            proDialog.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the class in which I send and the data from - `PhotosList`:

```
public class PhotosList {
    private String photo;
    private String shopname;

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getShopname() {
        return shopname;
    }

    public void setShopname(String shopname) {
        this.shopname = shopname;
    }
}
```

---

This is the `GridViewAdapter` that set data in the textviews e.t.c:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private List<PhotosList> photosarraylist = null;
    private ArrayList<PhotosList> arraylist;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, List<PhotosList> photosarraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.photosarraylist = photosarraylist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<PhotosList>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(photosarraylist);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView phone;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return photosarraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return photosarraylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item_viewphotos, null);
            // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
            holder.phone = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Load image into GridView
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(photosarraylist.get(position).getPhoto(),
                holder.phone);
        // Capture GridView item click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView_GridPhotosActivity.class);
                // Pass all data phone
                intent.putExtra("photo", photosarraylist.get(position).getPhoto());
                intent.putExtra("shopname", photosarraylist.get(position).getShopname());

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

---

This is the layout of the first fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    tools:context="guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all.ViewPhotoCommentActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/pattern9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/lessinfo"
                android:background="@drawable/less"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ecf0f1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/photos_grid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:columnWidth="120dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

And this is the layout of each gridview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I guess you have the first necessary step to start to share data on Parse (registration and initialize). I say that because in your model class (PhotoList) I didn't see any annotations about this.

Second and more important, I love Parse, and the best way if you're going to work with data and then to use adapters for Grid/List Views, is not extends of BaseAdapter, It's better ParseQueryAdapter.

You can get all data in the adapter and then, you can do whatever you want whit them, because like BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter, has getView method as well.

I recommend you take a look to these links:

(Example from GitHub) https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseQueryAdapterTutorial/blob/master/src/com/parse/samples/parsequeryadapter/CustomAdapter.java

(Official Doc) https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter

I hope you like! :)

Comment: Thank you, I will check it. I used code similar to the above but with ListViews and it is working great. The difference is the GridView. But I don't think that the problem has something to do with this. May I do something wrong with the logic and the flag is being changed in the process from true to false? Because I added this line: `Log.d("I AM HERE", Photo.getParseObject("name").fetchIfNeeded().getString("name"));` to check if I am getting the data correctly and it is working fine. So the problem is not with the data that I get but with the way I am using them in the `onPostExectute` maybe ?

Comment: Could you try to add a FindCallBack inside in query_photos.find() and put them all there?

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion and the example you posted about ParseQueryAdapter and it's working after some modifications. Thank you very much